# Show that for each natural number $n≥2,$ there exists $a\in\mathbb{N}$ with $(6a+1)a\equiv_n1$ (Irish TST)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Show that for each natural number $n≥2,$ there exists an integer $a>0$ such that $(6a+1)a$ leaves a remainder of $1$ upon division by $n.$

This question was on the Irish Team Selection Test for this year.

The question comes down to solving the congruence $6a^2 + a - 1\equiv_n0.$ We may factor this and write it as $(3a-1)(2a+1)\equiv_n0.$ So, if $n$ is odd, it suffices to take $a=\frac{n-1}{2}.$ If $n$ is $1$ mod $3,$ then $2n$ is $2$ mod $3,$ and hence we may take $a=\frac{2n+1}{3}.$ If $n$ is $2$ mod $3,$ take $a=\frac{n+1}{3}.$

The only case we are left with is when $n$ is a multiple of $6.$ I do not know how to proceed in this case. One thing I noticed is that in this case, taking $a=n-5$ works many times for small values of $n.$ This happens only for those $n$ that divide $144$ (and are multiples of $6,$ of course). It will be clear why this happens once $6a^2+a-1$ is expanded with $a=n-5.$ Beyond this, I have no idea.

How to deal with this case?

Comment: When $n=6c$ , then $a=6c+1$ will work ! You have already solved all other Cases !

Comment: @Prem, I am not sure that that works. Let $n=30.$ Then, $a=31$ gives $(6a+1)a\equiv_{30}7.$

Comment: If you can show it for n = power of 2 and power of 3 then probably by Chinese remainder theorem you can show it for power of 6

Comment: When $n=6c,a=6b+1$, then $(9b+1)(4b+1)$ must be a multiple of $c$

Comment: Let $\,n = 2^k m,\ 2\nmid m.\,$ CRT  $\Rightarrow \exists\,a\!:$  $\,a\equiv \frac{1}3\pmod{\!2^k},\,$ $\,a\equiv -\frac{1}2\pmod{\!m},\,$ so $\,2^k\mid 3a\!-\!1,\,$ $\,m\mid 2a\!+\!1,\,$ so $\ n=2^k m\mid (3a\!-\!1)(2a\!+\!1).\ $ This is a **duplicate**. $\ \ $

Comment: Finding a dupe target turned out to be easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: You are right , @aqualubix , that will not work. The Dup gives 3 alternative Solutions.